# Showing that $A=\mathfrak{a}$ for a certain ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ and a commutative ring $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $E$ an $A$-algebra with basis $e_1,e_2$ and unit element $e=\lambda e_1+\mu e_2$ for some $\lambda,\mu\in A$. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be the ideal generated by $\{\lambda,\mu\}$. I want to show that $A=\mathfrak{a}$.

From linear algebra, we know that $E\otimes_A(A/\mathfrak{a})\cong E/\mathfrak{a}E$. On the other hand, we have $\{0\}=E\otimes_A(A/\mathfrak{a})$ since $x\otimes\bar{1}=0$ for all $x\in E$.

Now, supposing $A\ne\mathfrak{a}$ (for the sake of contraction), it follows that $A/\mathfrak{a}\ne\{0\}$. What else do I need to derive a contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly $E$ is in particular a free $A$-module of rank 2 with generators $e_1,e_2$.

Hence in $\mathsf{Mod}_A$ we have $E \cong A^2$ and thus
$$0 = E \otimes A/\mathfrak{a} \cong A^2 \otimes A/\mathfrak{a} \cong (A \otimes A/\mathfrak{a})^2 \cong (A/\mathfrak{a})^2$$
But then $A/\mathfrak{a}=0$ follows, proving $\mathfrak{a}=A$.

Comment: This is better than a proof by contradiction. Thank you

Comment: I do like constructive proofs better too. And you are welcome :)